# Why does reopening (and closing) questions not work?

Tags: support

## Reopening

I recently received the gold badge for [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes), and the tag description says:

> These users can single-handedly mark [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes) questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed.

So I tried that with this post here:
[I can't randomly distribute the contents of a collection in Blender 3.0 geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241534/i-cant-randomly-distribute-the-contents-of-a-collection-in-blender-3-0-geometry)

Actually, I wanted to reopen the question first so that I could mark it as a duplicate, because technically it is identical to a previously answered question:
[How to distribute pebbles on the surface?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263548/how-to-distribute-pebbles-on-the-surface/)

But that didn't work the way it was described. The action was counted as a vote to reopen the question, and did not directly change the question.

What have I done wrong here?

Or does this not work as described?

Can I now reopen questions just like that, or not?

## Closing/Mark as Duplicate

I have just encountered another problem:

I was just able to reopen a question that I closed once before (along with others), but I can't close it again or mark it as a "duplicate".

The message I receive reads: *"You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote"*.

Specifically, the issue is that I wanted to mark [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263900/) as a duplicate to [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557).

I was able to open the question as I said, but now I can't close it.

Why?

---

...somehow this all doesn't seem to work so well here, without moderator rights. Maybe someone should take a closer look at these additional permissions, which are related to the gold badge. ;-)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the privilege doesn't seem to work if the question was closed by a moderator. It is now reopened, you may close again as duplicate

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Ah, OK, that could be, of course. Would be good to mention that in the description too, because it's a bit confusing that way. Thanks for reopening, the question has now been marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But that didn't work the way it was described. The action was counted as a vote to reopen the question, and did not directly change the question.

That's because it was [originally closed as 'not suitable for this site'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/241534/timeline#history_eba2b932-bfce-4948-93a8-be26186b5077), and your gold tag badge (congratulations!) only works for the 'duplicate' close reason.

> I was able to open the question as I said, but now I can't close it.

You [already voted to close this question before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/263900/timeline#history_9b96dc17-fcc6-46de-9327-fcddb882cdee), and regular users [can't vote to close a question more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137425/295232).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! As already mentioned in the comments, it might be good if this information somehow finds its way into the description of the additional privileges. For me it was a bit confusing. Anyway: problem solved!

Comment: @quellenform Just to add that most of the pages from the help center are not editable and the text is the same for all sites. We can't personalize it for our community nor add to it, as far as I know.